# MySQL Sort by two columns and the sort remaining records alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sorting, multiple-columns

I have three three columns in my MySQL table:

```
title, featured, sort_order
```

where `title` is `varchar`, `featured` is `enum` ("YES" or "NO") and `sort_order` is `int`.

I would like return the result set with featured as "YES" first and then sort the featured as "YES" with `sort_order` ascending (so, 0, 1, 2, 3, etc...) and then then sort the remaining records by `title ASC` (alphabetical).

I've look around at `GROUP BY`, etc. but am having issues finding the answer.

Hopefully what I'm trying to accomplish makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
select *, IF(featured = 'YES', 0, 1) AS ftsort, CAST(IF(featured = 'YES', sort_oder, title) AS CHAR) AS nosort 
from table
order by ftsort ASC, nosort ASC
```

Comment: Bah... I just realized that this isn't right either.  It does separate the yes/no's, but the no's are still sorting by sort order first, then alpha.  This is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: This runs into the same problem my previous attempt at an answer (now deleted) did.  Once you initiate a ORDER BY, a the type of the first value sorted is used for future comparisons.  Meaning, you begin Ordering by an INT but then swap to a Varchar() which throws an exception 'Can't convert varchar to int.  Alas, I think the only way to achieve this is to execute the queries separately, and create a new result combining the two.

Comment: This appears to be working - and on a large result set. Thank you so much. I would have never figured this out. If anyone can recommend some good books on MySQL that'd be great. For years I've gotten by with the basics but I'd love a resource to learn more! There seems to be so many ways to do things...

Comment: This might work but the readability is average and you can not mix `ASC` and `DESC` order sequences.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY effects the result set you are getting which is what you don't want: you need to use ORDER BY when sorting returned values in a particular way:

```
SELECT FEATURED, SORT_ORDER, TITLE FROM your_table
ORDER BY FEATURED, TITLE ASC, SORT_ORDER
```

Comment: This does not work. But thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like DiscipleMichael mentioned, you can not use `UNION` with a `SELECT` using an `ORDER BY` clause.  But there is a workaround, you can wrap the ordered queries inside a subselect.

Here is how I would do it :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT title, featured FROM yourTable WHERE featured = 'YES' ORDER BY sort_order) AS featuredYES
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT title, featured FROM yourTable WHERE featured = 'NO' ORDER BY title) AS featuredNO
```

This is probably better than messing with `if`s :

- it is more readable;
- it allows you to easily add another order sequence if needed;
- it allows you to mix `ASC` and `DESC` order sequences if needed.

Comment: Missing `From` clause.  When added, MySql reports "incorrect usage of Union and Order BY".  A custom procedure may be in need.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael Thx.  I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the below sql into MySQL (where needed) and this will do the trick.

```
DECLARE @myTable as Table
(
    title varchar(50),
    featured varchar(3),
    sort_order int
)

Insert INTO @myTable
    SELECT title, featured, sort_order
    FROM test1
    WHERE featured = 'YES'
    ORDER BY sort_order

Insert INTO @myTable
    SELECT title, featured, sort_order
    FROM test1
    WHERE featured = 'NO'
    ORDER BY title ASC

SELECT * FROM @myTable
```

I Believe the below MySQL version is correct (please verify).

```
Create TEMPORARY TABLE myTable 
(
    title varchar(50),
    featured varchar(3),
    sort_order int
);

Insert INTO myTable
    (SELECT title, featured, sort_order
    FROM test1
    WHERE featured = 'YES'
    ORDER BY sort_order);

Insert INTO myTable
    (SELECT title, featured, sort_order
    FROM test1
    WHERE featured = 'NO'
    ORDER BY title ASC);

SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Of course, my field types maybe different than yours, just modify the create statement to the correct types.